# Convert a table column to a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a Table (T) as shown below:

```
>> Name = {'John';'Mary';'Martha'};
Age = [10.8;15.11;20.22];
T=table(Name,Age);
>> T

T =

  3×2 table

      Name       Age 
    ________    _____

    'John'       10.8
    'Mary'      15.11
    'Martha'    20.22
```

Converting the Age column to a matrix works fine, if I use:

```
cell2mat(table2cell(T(:,2)))
```

But doesn't work if I use:

```
cell2mat(table2cell(T.Age))
```

and throws the following errror:

```
>> cell2mat(table2cell(T.Age))
Undefined function 'getVars' for input
arguments of type 'double'.

Error in table2cell (line 15)
t_vars = getVars(t);
```

Is there any way I could use the column name **T.Age** instead using **T(:,2)** while converting this column into a matrix ?

Comment: `T.Age` is a matrix...

Answer (score 4):

From the [Access Data in a Table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) doc on the MathWorks site

> Parentheses allow you to select a subset of the data in a table and preserve the table container.

while

> Dot indexing extracts data from one table variable. The result is an array of the same data type as extracted variable. You can follow the dot indexing with parentheses to specify a subset of rows to extract from a variable.

So, if you use `T.Age` to access the data, the result should already be a matrix, i.e. you don't need to do any conversions using `table2cell` or `cell2mat`.